How to resolve the error Property 'vars' does not exist on type 'Theme' in Material UI
I am trying to clone this project locally
https://github.com/mui/material-ui/tree/v6.1.9/docs/data/material/getting-started/templates/marketing-page
I git cloned the project and moved shared-theme and marketing-page into my project as mentioned in README but I keep getting this error that
borderRadius: (theme.vars || theme).shape.borderRadius,

Property 'vars' does not exist on type 'Theme'.ts(2339)
I also installed all the npm libraries mentioned in the README.
What am I doing wrong here?

Remember that if following the instructions result in errors, you should report that problem to the maintainers of those instructions.

I read their read me for this, they recommend if your question does not require a code change then I should ask on stack overflow which is what I did. I am pretty there is nothing wrong with their code. It is something missing on my part mostly but just can't figure out what it is. :)

To fix this typescript error, add the following line:
import type {} from '@mui/material/themeCssVarsAugmentation';

see https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/css-theme-variables/usage/#typescript
